# Summing Rows in Matrices created by lapply

Tags: r, lapply, rowsum

I'm brand new to R and I'm trying to figure out how to sum the rows from the following output.

```
u <- c(1,2,3)
x <- lapply(u, replicate, rbinom(10,1,.5))
```

When I do this x is equal to

```
[[1]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    1
[10,]    0

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    1
 [2,]    0    1
 [3,]    1    0
 [4,]    1    1
 [5,]    1    1
 [6,]    1    1
 [7,]    1    1
 [8,]    1    0
 [9,]    1    0
[10,]    0    0

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    0    1
 [4,]    1    0    1
 [5,]    0    0    1
 [6,]    0    0    1
 [7,]    0    1    0
 [8,]    1    1    1
 [9,]    0    1    1
[10,]    0    1    1
```

When I use the coding

```
rowSums(x)
```

or

```
rowSums(x[2])
```

I get this error

```
Error in rowSums(x) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

How can I sum the rows?  Also, is there a way to break up the tables so that I can do individual analysis.  Preferably a way that is not manual so I can use it if I have 100+ tables

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(x, rowSums)`? Keeping such objects organized in lists is typically the preferred method in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop over the individual elements of the list is conveniently performed using `lapply()`. You could try this:

```
lapply(x, rowSums)
#[[1]]
# [1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 0 1
# 
#[[3]]
# [1] 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

**data:**

```
u <- c(1,2,3)
set.seed(123)
x <- lapply(u, replicate, rbinom(10,1,.5))
```